- In plugin 'com.facebook.react' type 'com.facebook.react.tasks.BundleHermesCTask' property 'entryFile' specifies file which doesn't exist
While building Android APK, I got an issue saying:

In plugin 'com.facebook.react' type 'com.facebook.react.tasks.BundleHermesCTask' property 'entryFile' specifies file '../index.js' which doesn't exist

Any help ?

After quick searches, I got two working solutions:

By renaming the the entry file in your project root, from index.** to index.js

By configuring android/app/build.gradle:
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
/**

This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
*/
react {
...
entryFile = file("../index.js") // index.js (or whatever the entry file name is) is the entry file in the root project folder
}



